# NVDA screen reader aria-live issue

Tags: html, wai-aria, screen-readers, nvda

Using `aria-live` to show form field validation error dynamically. Everything works, except when moving from one field to another using down arrow key/tab the validation error is only get announced once the next file label is selected, and reads that next label name then announces the previous fields validation error.

Code:

```
{!label ? null : <label htmlFor={`input-${model}`} className={classnames('inputLabel', `${model.toLowerCase()}-label`)}>{label}&nbsp;<i className={ classnames('fa','fa-asterisk', { 'isRequired' : requiredField }, { 'invisible' : !requiredField || !showAsterisk } )} aria-hidden='true'></i></label>}              
            {!label ? null : <br />}
            <OverlayTrigger ref={(input) => { this.refPopOver = input; }} trigger={trigger} placement={popoverPlacement} overlay={popover} shouldUpdatePosition={true}>
                <InputComponent model={`.${model}`}

                    {...extraProps} />
            </OverlayTrigger>
            <div id='errorRegion' aria-atomic="true" aria-live="assertive">
                <Errors
                    className={classnames('errorText', 'error', model.toLowerCase())}
                    model={`.${model}`}
                    wrapper={ErrorWrapper}
                    show="touched"
                    messages={validators.messages}
                />
            </div>
```

EDIT:
slugolicious- thanks for you update. yes, I am using aria-live for announcing error. It works fine when using tab to go through the focusable elements. But when using browse mode using down arrow the sequence of announcing error and next label gets mixed up, I have also tried you suggestion but still the same result; its announce next label then error message of previous field. adding log of NVDA(v2017.4 & v2018.1) using Firefox (59.0.2 x64) below-

[NVDA speech viewer log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dI6k2.png) 
Second Edit: before the live regions are populated

```
<form style="position: relative;" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="id-form-errors" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
                <!-- react-empty: 170 -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
            <div style="position: relative;">
                <label class="inputLabel firstname-label" for="input-firstName">
                    <!-- react-text: 175 -->First name
                    <!-- /react-text -->
                    <!-- react-text: 176 -->&nbsp;
                    <!-- /react-text -->
                    <i class="fa fa-asterisk isRequired" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </label>
                <br>
                <input name="appForms.identify.firstName" class="field fullWidth firstname-field" id="input-firstName" aria-required="true"
                    aria-describedby="firstname-popover" type="text" placeholder="First name" value="">
                <div id="errorRegion" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
                    <!-- react-empty: 181 -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
            <div style="position: relative;">
                <label class="inputLabel lastname-label" for="input-lastName">
                    <!-- react-text: 185 -->Last name
                    <!-- /react-text -->
                    <!-- react-text: 186 -->&nbsp;
                    <!-- /react-text -->
                    <i class="fa fa-asterisk isRequired" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </label>
                <br>
                <input name="appForms.identify.lastName" class="field fullWidth lastname-field" id="input-lastName" aria-required="true"
                    aria-describedby="lastname-popover" type="text" placeholder="Last name" value="">
                <div id="errorRegion" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
                    <!-- react-empty: 191 -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <button class="submitButton fullWidth disabledButton next-btn" aria-disabled="true" type="submit">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

HTML After error regions are generated:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <div style="position: relative;">
            <label for="input-firstName" class="inputLabel firstname-label">
                <!-- react-text: 226 -->First name
                <!-- /react-text -->
                <!-- react-text: 227 -->&nbsp;
                <!-- /react-text -->
                <i class="fa fa-asterisk isRequired" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </label>
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="field fullWidth firstname-field" placeholder="First name" id="input-firstName" aria-describedby="firstname-popover"
                aria-required="true" name="appForms.identify.firstName" value="">
            <div id="errorRegion" aria-atomic="true" aria-live="assertive">
                <!-- react-empty: 232 -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <div style="position: relative;">
            <label for="input-lastName" class="inputLabel lastname-label">
                <!-- react-text: 236 -->Last name
                <!-- /react-text -->
                <!-- react-text: 237 -->&nbsp;
                <!-- /react-text -->
                <i class="fa fa-asterisk isRequired" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </label>
            <br>
            <input type="text" class="field fullWidth lastname-field" placeholder="Last name" id="input-lastName" aria-describedby="lastname-popover"
                aria-required="true" name="appForms.identify.lastName" value="">
            <div id="errorRegion" aria-atomic="true" aria-live="assertive">
                <!-- react-empty: 242 -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

3rd EDIT- Still waiting for a workable solution. Need help!

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure we're talking about the same thing, using `aria-live` is for when content on your page updates and you want the update announced immediately by the screen reader.  The update is announced once and then it's done.  Having error messages announced via `aria-live` is a good practice.

If the user then navigates through the page, either tabbing around to interactive elements, or using the virtual cursor in a screen reader, your error messages will **not** be announced unless you've associated them with the field that contains the error, often via the `aria-describedby` attribute.  You should also use `aria-invalid="true"` on fields that are invalid.

Comment: updated the original post please see if you have any solution for this- thanks in advance

Comment: if you have straight html, i might be able to help, but your code example has a bunch of other programming logic so it's difficult to see what's generated.

Comment: added the html before and after the error regions are generated.

Comment: The second code snippet just has `<div class="row">`.  The two  `<div class="row">` sections in both snippets are the same, other than the order of some of the attributes.  Shouldn't the second one have an element with "Your first name is required" as shown in your NVDA speech viewer image?